# how to find xml nodes with an id specified in another nodes using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

So, i have xml document like that :

```
<main>
    <objects>
        <object>
            <objectid>1</objectid>
            <parentid>0</parentid>
            <type>1</type>
        </object>
        <object>
            <objectid>2</objectid>
            <parentid>1</parentid>
            <type>2</type>
        </object>
        <object>
            <objectid>3</objectid>
            <parentid>1</parentid>
            <type>1</type>
        </object>
        <object>
            <objectid>4</objectid>
            <parentid>2</parentid>
            <type>2</type>
        </object>
    </objects>
</main>
```

Can I find, using xpath, all nodes having `type = 2` and nodes having `objectid` = `parentid` of this node ?

With *xmllint*, i can find all nodes wwith given type:

```
 xpath //main/objects/object[type[text()=2]]
```

but what next? (search should return first, third and fourth node `object`)

Comment: That would return an *empty set* in your example (since there is no `object` with an `objectId` with the same value as a `parentId`). Is that what you want?

Comment: object with objectid=4 has parentid = 2; i want to find object with objectid=2

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear, do you want to find the nodes that have type = 2 and the objected of that node is equal to the parentid of that node?

```
/main/objects/object[type[text()='2'] and objectid = parentid]
```

But you this will return none of the objects in the example?

Comment: i want to find the nodes that (A) have type = 2 plus (B) the nodes that have objectid = parentid of nodes from (A)

Comment: But this is not possible to do with one expression, because you can select the objects with type 2 but then you can't go back in the three off the xml to select the object that have the objected as parentid.

Comment: Are you using it in xslt or were are you using it, because then you have to save the selection in a variable and then do the second selection with an other expression on the variable

Comment: at the moment i'am using xmllint; i don't know if it allows to use xslt

Comment: Where do you want to use the output of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want to obtain, so I'm including several alternatives for selection of objects based on their children.

The object that you call "parents" in your document (the ones that are referred via a `parentid` by sibling objects) can be selected using:

```
//main/objects/object[objectid=../object/parentid]
```

which will select the first two `object` nodes in your example.

You can add additional *predicates*, to further restrict the selection. If you want the above restriction only in the context of the elements that have `type='2'`, then you can use:

```
//main/objects/object[type='2'][objectid=../object/parentid]
```

which will select only the second node.

Inverting that (selecting nodes whose `parentid` is equal to any sibling's `objectid` would select the last three nodes:

```
/main/objects/object[parentid=../object/objectid]
```

Restricting the context to the `type='2'` nodes, then you get the second and the last `object` elements with this expression:

```
/main/objects/object[type='2'][parentid=../object/objectid]
```